# Rendering JSON output on Flask Bootstrap Page

Tags: python, json, twitter-bootstrap, pandas, flask

I am trying to display JSON File from Flask into my HTML Page.

**Flask**

```
@app.route("/analysis")
def analysis():
    data = pd.read_csv('static/uploads/' + global_file.filename)
    temp_json = data.to_json(orient='records')
    json_df = json.loads(temp_json)
    list = json_df
    return render_template('results.html', summary = json.dumps(list))
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="results">
    <table>
        {% for key in summary %}
            {{ key.Name }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </div>
```

**JSON**

```
Name    Age Class   Marks
A       12     6    32
B       13     6    32
C       14     6    43
D       12     6    54
E       13     6    23
```

I am getting blank page as ouptut. I want to display it as a pretty table on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can convert values to dictionary first and then loop for table:

```
@app.route("/analysis")
def analysis():
    data = pd.read_csv('static/uploads/' + global_file.filename)
    temp_dict = data.to_dict(orient='records')
    return render_template('results.html', summary = temp_dict)
```

---

```
<table>
  {% for value in summary %}
    <tr>
         <td> {{ value['Name'] }} </td>
         <td> {{ value['Age'] }} </td>
         <td> {{ value['Class'] }} </td>
         <td> {{ value['Marks'] }} </td>     
    </tr>
  {%  endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is you convert the json object into a string using `json.dumps` Then you iterate through the string (character by character) and try to access `Name` attribute. If you leave out the `.Name`, you will indeed see every character printed out after eachother.

To fix this you should provide the template with the actual object: a `list` of `dicts`. Like so:

```
@app.route("/analysis")
def analysis():
    data = pd.read_csv('static/uploads/' + global_file.filename)
    temp_json = data.to_json(orient='records')
    json_df = json.loads(temp_json)
    return render_template('results.html', summary = json_df)
```

Then still there won't be an actual table, because in your template there are no `tr` or `td` elements. If you fix that:

```
<div class="results">
     <table>
         {% for item in summary %}
             <tr><td>
             {{ item['Name'] }}
             </td></tr>
         {% endfor %}
     </table>
</div>
```

You will see an actual table.

EDIT:
Also the conversions inside of your analyse method are a bit superfluous, but maybe you shortened your code to post here?